# Why are my chunks not showing in my Unity voxels engine?

Tags: unity, c#, procedural-generation, voxels

I created a voxel engine in Unity. It worked fine until yesterday when I tried to remove the faces between chunks to create a seamless world.

Now there's just an empty world when entering the game. I hope that you can help me.

On a side note, I have an idea why it doesn't work. Lines 143 and 144 in Chunk.cs don't seem to be executed, that's why there are no blocks added, but I don't have an idea what's causing this.

Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Chunk : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public int UnloadingDistance;
    public string pos;

    public static int CHUNK_DIMENSION = 16;

    void Update()
    {
        if ((transform.position - player.position).magnitude > UnloadingDistance)
        {
            Unload();
        }
    }

    public void Unload()
    {
        //TODO save
        Player.chunks.Remove(pos);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    public static void Load(Transform player,int LoadingDistance,int UnloadingDistance)
    {
        Vector3 start = player.position - new Vector3(LoadingDistance, LoadingDistance, LoadingDistance);
        Vector3 end = player.position + new Vector3(LoadingDistance, LoadingDistance, LoadingDistance);
        start.x = Mathf.Clamp(start.x, -50000000, 50000000);
        end.x = Mathf.Clamp(end.x, -50000000, 50000000);
        start.y = Mathf.Clamp(start.y, 0, 512);
        end.y = Mathf.Clamp(end.y, 0, 512);
        start.z = Mathf.Clamp(start.z, -50000000, 50000000);
        end.z = Mathf.Clamp(end.z, -50000000, 50000000);
        for (int x = Mathf.FloorToInt(start.x / CHUNK_DIMENSION) * CHUNK_DIMENSION; x < Mathf.FloorToInt(end.x / CHUNK_DIMENSION) * CHUNK_DIMENSION; x += CHUNK_DIMENSION)
        {
            for (int y = Mathf.FloorToInt(start.y / CHUNK_DIMENSION) * CHUNK_DIMENSION; y < Mathf.FloorToInt(end.y / CHUNK_DIMENSION) * CHUNK_DIMENSION; y += CHUNK_DIMENSION)
            {
                for (int z = Mathf.FloorToInt(start.z / CHUNK_DIMENSION) * CHUNK_DIMENSION; z < Mathf.FloorToInt(end.z / CHUNK_DIMENSION) * CHUNK_DIMENSION; z += CHUNK_DIMENSION)
                {
                    if ((new Vector3(x,y,z)-player.position).magnitude > LoadingDistance) { continue; }
                    if (!Player.chunks.ContainsKey(x.ToString() + ";" + y.ToString() + ";" + z.ToString()))
                    {
                        loadChunk(x, y, z, UnloadingDistance, LoadingDistance, player);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void loadChunk(int x, int y, int z, int UnloadingDistance, int LoadingDistance, Transform player)
    {
        GameObject chunk = Instantiate(Player.ChunkPrefab);
        chunk.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        Chunk c = chunk.GetComponent<Chunk>();
        c.pos = x.ToString() + ";" + y.ToString() + ";" + z.ToString();
        c.UnloadingDistance = UnloadingDistance;
        c.player = player;
        Player.chunks.Add(c.pos, c);

        new Thread(delegate () {
            List<Vector3> verts = new List<Vector3>();
            List<int> tris = new List<int>();
            List<Vector2> uvs = new List<Vector2>();
            List<Vector3> norms = new List<Vector3>();
            List<int> types = new List<int>();
            List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>();

            int[,,] existants = new int[CHUNK_DIMENSION + 2, CHUNK_DIMENSION + 2, CHUNK_DIMENSION + 2];

            System.Random r = new System.Random();
            for (int bx = -1; bx < CHUNK_DIMENSION + 1; bx++)
            {
                for (int bz = -1; bz < CHUNK_DIMENSION + 1; bz++)
                {
                    int perlinHeight = Mathf.RoundToInt(Mathf.PerlinNoise(0.01f * (bx + x) + 0.001f, 0.01f * (bz + z) + 0.001f) * 100f) + 156;
                    for (int by = -1; by < CHUNK_DIMENSION + 1; by++)
                    {
                        Vector3 cPos = new Vector3(
                            x + (bx < 0 ? -1 : bx < CHUNK_DIMENSION ? 0 : 1),
                            y + (by < 0 ? -1 : by < CHUNK_DIMENSION ? 0 : 1),
                            z + (bz < 0 ? -1 : bz < CHUNK_DIMENSION ? 0 : 1)
                        );
                        Vector3 bPos = new Vector3(
                            bx < 0 ? CHUNK_DIMENSION - 1 : bx >= CHUNK_DIMENSION ? 0 : bx,
                            by < 0 ? CHUNK_DIMENSION - 1 : by >= CHUNK_DIMENSION ? 0 : by,
                            bz < 0 ? CHUNK_DIMENSION - 1 : bz >= CHUNK_DIMENSION ? 0 : bz
                        );
                        int type = -1;
                        if (Player.WorldData != "")
                        {
                            string btype = Player.tryGetB64Arr(Player.WorldData, new int[] { (int)cPos.x, (int)cPos.y, (int)cPos.z, (int)bPos.x, (int)bPos.y, (int)bPos.z });
                            if (btype != "")
                            {
                                type = Convert.ToInt16(btype);
                            }
                        }
                        if (type == -1)
                        {
                            if (by + y > perlinHeight)
                            {
                                if (by + y < Player.SeaLevel)
                                {
                                    type = Player.WaterBlock;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            else if (by + y == perlinHeight)
                            {
                                type = Player.ToppingBlock;
                            }
                            else if (by + y == 0)
                            {
                                type = Player.GroundBorderBlock;
                            }
                            else if (by + y < Player.GroundMedianBorder * perlinHeight)
                            {
                                type = Player.GroundBlocks[r.Next(0, Player.GroundBlocks.Length - 1)];
                            }
                            else if (by + y < Player.MedianUpperBorder * perlinHeight)
                            {
                                type = Player.MedianBlocks[r.Next(0, Player.MedianBlocks.Length - 1)];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                type = Player.UpperBlocks[r.Next(0, Player.UpperBlocks.Length - 1)];
                            }
                        }
                        if (type == -1)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        existants[bx+1, by+1, bz+1] = Player.TransparentBlocks.Contains((int)type) ? 1 : 2;
                        if (bx > -1 && bx < CHUNK_DIMENSION && by > -1 && by < CHUNK_DIMENSION && bz > -1 && bz < CHUNK_DIMENSION)
                        {
                            types.Add(type);
                            positions.Add(new Vector3(bx, by, bz));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < types.Count;i++)
            {
                addBlock(verts, tris, uvs, norms, types[i], positions[i],existants);
            }

            Player.LoaderQueue.Add(delegate ()
            {
                if (chunk == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                Mesh mesh = chunk.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
                mesh.SetVertices(verts);
                mesh.SetTriangles(tris, 0);
                mesh.SetUVs(0, uvs);
                mesh.SetNormals(norms);
                mesh.RecalculateTangents();
                chunk.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
                chunk.GetComponent<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh = mesh;
            });
        }).Start();
    }

    private static void addBlock(List<Vector3> verts,List<int> tris, List<Vector2> uvs, List<Vector3> norms,float type,Vector3 localPos, int[,,] existants)
    {
        Debug.Log(type + ";" + localPos);
        float us = (type % 8f) / 8f + 0.0002f;
        float vs = Mathf.Floor(type / 8f) / 8f + 0.0002f;
        float ue = us + 0.1246f;
        float ve = vs + 0.1246f;
        int si = 0;
        int selfLevel = Player.TransparentBlocks.Contains((int)type) ? 1 : 2;

        selfLevel = 10;

        //back
        if (existants[(int)localPos.x,(int)localPos.y,(int)localPos.z-1] < selfLevel)
        {
            si = verts.Count;
            verts.Add(new Vector3(0, 0, 0) + localPos);
            uvs.Add(new Vector2(us, vs));
            verts.Add(new Vector3(0, 1, 0) + localPos);
            uvs.Add(new Vector2(us, ve));
            verts.Add(new Vector3(1, 0, 0) + localPos);
            uvs.Add(new Vector2(ue, vs));
            verts.Add(new Vector3(1, 1, 0) + localPos);
            uvs.Add(new Vector2(ue, ve));
            norms.Add(Vector3.back);
            norms.Add(Vector3.back);
            norms.Add(Vector3.back);
            norms.Add(Vector3.back);
            tris.Add(si); tris.Add(si + 1); tris.Add(si + 2);
            tris.Add(si + 2); tris.Add(si + 1); tris.Add(si + 3);
        }

        //front
        if (existants[(int)localPos.x,(int)localPos.y,(int)localPos.z + 1] < selfLevel)
        {
            si = verts.Count;
            verts.Add(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) + localPos);
            uvs.Add(new Vector2(us, vs));
            verts.Add(new Vector3(1, 0, 1) + localPos);
            uvs.Add(new Vector2(ue, vs));
            verts.Add(new Vector3(1, 1, 1) + localPos);
            uvs.Add(new Vector2(ue, ve));
            verts.Add(new Vector3(0, 1, 1) + localPos);
            uvs.Add(new Vector2(us, ve));
            norms.Add(Vector3.forward);
            norms.Add(Vector3.forward);
            norms.Add(Vector3.forward);
            norms.Add(Vector3.forward);
            tris.Add(si); tris.Add(si + 1); tris.Add(si + 2);
            tris.Add(si); tris.Add(si + 2); tris.Add(si + 3);
        }

        //right
        if (existants[(int)localPos.x+1,(int)localPos.y,(int)localPos.z] < selfLevel)
        {
            si = verts.Count;
            verts.Add(new Vector3(1, 0, 1) + localPos);
            uvs.Add(new Vector2(us, ve));
            verts.Add(new Vector3(1, 0, 0) + localPos);
            uvs.Add(new Vector2(us, vs));
            verts.Add(new Vector3(1, 1, 0) + localPos);
            uvs.Add(new Vector2(ue, vs));
            verts.Add(new Vector3(1, 1, 1) + localPos);
            uvs.Add(new Vector2(ue, ve));
            norms.Add(Vector3.right);
            norms.Add(Vector3.right);
            norms.Add(Vector3.right);
            norms.Add(Vector3.right);
            tris.Add(si); tris.Add(si + 1); tris.Add(si + 2);
            tris.Add(si); tris.Add(si + 2); tris.Add(si + 3);
        }

        //left
        if (existants[(int)localPos.x-1,(int)localPos.y,(int)localPos.z] < selfLevel)
        {
            si = verts.Count;
            verts.Add(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) + localPos);
            uvs.Add(new Vector2(us, ve));
            verts.Add(new Vector3(0, 1, 0) + localPos);
            uvs.Add(new Vector2(ue, vs));
            verts.Add(new Vector3(0, 0, 0) + localPos);
            uvs.Add(new Vector2(us, vs));
            verts.Add(new Vector3(0, 1, 1) + localPos);
            uvs.Add(new Vector2(ue, ve));
            norms.Add(Vector3.left);
            norms.Add(Vector3.left);
            norms.Add(Vector3.left);
            norms.Add(Vector3.left);
            tris.Add(si); tris.Add(si + 1); tris.Add(si + 2);
            tris.Add(si); tris.Add(si + 3); tris.Add(si + 1);
        }

        //top
        if (existants[(int)localPos.x,(int)localPos.y+1,(int)localPos.z] < selfLevel)
        {
            si = verts.Count;
            verts.Add(new Vector3(1, 1, 0) + localPos);
            uvs.Add(new Vector2(ue, vs));
            verts.Add(new Vector3(0, 1, 1) + localPos);
            uvs.Add(new Vector2(us, ve));
            verts.Add(new Vector3(1, 1, 1) + localPos);
            uvs.Add(new Vector2(ue, ve));
            verts.Add(new Vector3(0, 1, 0) + localPos);
            uvs.Add(new Vector2(us, vs));
            norms.Add(Vector3.up);
            norms.Add(Vector3.up);
```

Comment: To avoid such problems in the future you might want to start using version control and do a commit whenever you accomplished something. That way you can revert to a previous version whenever you broke something and don't remember how it looked before.

Comment: I'm currently not able to do that, because I don't have internet at home, but you're right I could have made a backup

Comment: Version control doesn't need to be online. Both Visual Studio and MonoDevelop support GIT which is completely client-sided with pushes to online repositories being completely optional.

Comment: Ok. I thought that I need a repo for this. thanks!

Comment: Please add all and only relevant code to this question directly incase the link dies.

Comment: I added the code in the question. It's the whole class because I don't know wich part is causing my problem

Comment: @TimoHo A repo doesn't need to be online, it can also be local.

Comment: with repo I meant some thing like bitbucket. Thanks to Philipp, I started using version control.

Comment: As a side note, there are several levels of inefficiency here, which you may want to address. For example, in update you are checking magnitude of the distance vector to tell whether to unload the chunk. A more efficient check is to use the sqrMagnitude so that performing an expensive sqrt operation every frame is unnecessary: `if ((transform.position - player.position).sqrMagnitude > UnloadingDistance * UnloadingDistance)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. It was an IndexOutOfRangeException when getting/setting values in the existants array, that didn't show up in unity and just ended the thread. Although the faces between chunks are still visible.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this accepted if you no longer need help with it. Otherwise the Community user will keep bumping the thread periodically to try to get more answers.